# PDFView for Multiplatform SwiftUI

Tags: swift, pdf, swiftui

I'm trying to create a PDFView for Multiplatform in SwiftUI, but I have run into multiple issues, e.g. Compiler not finding NSViewRepresentable, Compiler not finding PDFView etc. My code is below.

```
import SwiftUI
import PDFKit
import UIKit

struct ContentView: View {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sample", withExtension: "pdf")!
    
    var body: some View {
        PDFKitView(pdfData: PDFDocument(url: url)!)
    }
}

#if os(ios)
struct PDFKitView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let pdfData: PDFDocument
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PDFView {
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        pdfView.document = self.pdfData
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        return pdfView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ pdfView: PDFView, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
#else
struct PDFKitView: NSViewRepresentable {
    
    let pdfData: PDFDocument
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> PDFView {
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        pdfView.document = self.pdfData
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        return pdfView
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ pdfView: PDFView, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
#endif
```

I already tried to import some more stuff like UIKit, differentiating between iOS and macOS, etc...

Comment: Use #if canImport(AppKit) instead of else